# ImageMagick SVG to PNG not colorizing

Tags: linux, svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have ImageMagick installed on my Mac OS, Linux 64bit (2 systems) and RedHat.

I have a simple SVG file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <rect x="15" y="15" style="fill:none;" width="70" height="70"/>
        <path d="M85,0H15H0v15v70v15h15h70h15V85V15V0H85z M85,85H15V15h70V85z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

When I convert it on MAC OSX, RedHat or even one of my Linux setup using:

```
convert -fill 'rgb(255,0,0)' image.svg test.png
```

it converts the file correctly i.e. it changes it color to red.

However, on other Linux setup it does not colorize it, but remains in black color.

On all of the systems I installed ImageMagick from source. All have same version. All gives `"rsvg-convert" -o "%o" "%i"` when I execute:

```
convert -list delegate | grep 'svg => '
```

But I don't know why one of my Linux setup it does not work well as expected.

Comment: rgb takes 3 arguments (rgba would take 4). Does fixing that fix your issue?

Comment: I put an extra argument here by mistake. I actually used 3 arguments but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

Add `-verbose` to your convert command:

```
convert -verbose -fill 'rgba(255,0,0,0)' image.svg test.png
```

Then test again on each of your systems. Compare the output for each case.

`-verbose` reports in the terminal output which exact *delegate* command line will be run in the background to bring about a final format that ImageMagick can process itself.

For example, on my current system (OSX Mavericks), because I have a different setup from yours, my conversion doesn't fill red into the SVG, and I get to see this in the terminal:

```
"/opt/local/bin/inkscape" "/var/tmp/magick-31893m0w2-x4pHlPY" \
      --export-eps="/var/tmp/magick-31893y4-KtfXirywn" \
      --export-dpi="90,90" --export-background="rgb(100%,100%,100%)" \
      --export-background-opacity="1" > \
        "/var/tmp/magick-31893J8WlJy8Sn0uH" 2>&1
/var/tmp/magick-31893M9guCq3EvFL71 PNG 80x80 80x80+0+0 8-bit sRGB 351B 0.000u 0:00.000
/var/tmp/magick-31893y4-KtfXirywn PS 80x80 80x80+0+0 16-bit sRGB 351B 0.000u 0:00.000
img.svg=>/var/tmp/magick-31893y4-KtfXirywn PS 80x80 80x80+0+0 16-bit sRGB 351B 0.000u 0:00.000
img.svg=>out.png PS 80x80 80x80+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3c 463B 0.000u 0:00.000
[ghostscript library] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT \
        -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 \
       "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 \
       "-r72x72" -g80x80  "-sOutputFile=/var/tmp/magick-31893M9guCq3EvFL7%d" \
       "-f/var/tmp/magick-31893VjGeCPBsW7zN" \
       "-f/var/tmp/magick-31893OxqHgutvF5QZ"
```

As you can see, in my case there will be Inkscape as a delegate converting the SVG to EPS, then Ghostscript to convert the EPS to PNG (with alpha channel)....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
convert -fill 'rgb(255,0,0)' MSVG:test.svg test.png
```

It uses ImageMagick's own SVG internal renderer, MSVG, instead of the RSVG library.  More info here: http://imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#svg

However, MSVG is not a complete SVG converter, so some SVG files might not be rendered correctly.